# The last list elements and conditional loops

Tags: python

```
mylist="'a','b','c'"

count=0
i=0

while count< len(mylist):
    if mylist[i]==mylist[i+1]:
        print mylist[i]
    count +=1
    i +=1
```

Error:

```
File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
IndexError: string index out of range
```

I'm assuming that when it gets to the last (nth) element it can't find an n+1 to compare it to, so it gives me an error.

Interestingly, i think that I've done this before and not had this problem on a larger list: Here is an example (with credit to Raymond Hettinger for fixing it up)

```
list=['a','a','x','c','e','e','f','f','f']

i=0
count = 0

while count < len(list)-2:
    if list[i] == list[i+1]:
        if list [i+1] != list [i+2]:
            print list[i]
            i+=1
            count +=1
        else:
            print "no"
            count += 1
    else:   
        i +=1
        count += 1
```

For crawling through a list in the way I've attempted, is there any fix so that I don't go "out of range?" I plan to implement this on a very large list, where I'll have to check if "list[i]==list[i+16]", for example. In the future, I would like to add on conditions like "if int(mylist[i+3])-int(mylist[i+7])>10: newerlist.append[mylist[i]". So it's important that I solve this problem.

I thought about inserting a break statement, but was unsuccessful.

I know this is not the most efficient, but I'm at the point where it's what i understand best.

Comment: could you briefly explain what you are trying to achieve? most cases of `while counter < len(list): [...], i+= 1` can be better solved with other patterns

Comment: I'm trying to compare list[i] with list[i+n] and print list[i] if some relationship between them holds.

Comment: Please make it clear what you are trying to achieve (overall, not just the problem you have). It will make it much easier to give a useful answer. It's also worth noting `list` is a bad name for a variable, as it means you can't access the `list()` built-in function.

Comment: I'll clarify my comment again - you are asking how to solve a problem in your solution to your problem. I believe that the solution you are working towards isn't optimal. If you tell us what the problem you are trying to solve with this code is, we will be able to provide a lot more insight. tomislav-maric suggested you are trying to count the number of duplicate items in the list, for example - and this can be achieved with a single line of code.

Comment: Lattyware: I have a large list that looks like ["'John','Sally','5','10','11','4'", 'John','Sally','3','7','7','10','Bill','Hallie','4','6','2','1', etc...], where list[0],list[0+6], etc... are all men, list [1], [1+6], etc... are all their respective spouses, and then the next numbers represent each man's number of children, height, income, and   number of address. In the first two cases you can see that John and Sally are listed twice. If that's the case, I would like to take them and all their respective info and put them into a new list.

Comment: If they are listed 3 or more times, I would like to put them into a different list. Each male+spouse is listed at least twice.

Comment: Once I have the pairs, I would like to look at the differences between the couples "numbers" and if these differences fit certain criteria, I would like to split them into smaller lists. I know this sounds kind of weird--but it's essentially exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: It sounds like your data structure is really weird. You would probably be best off restructuring using dictionaries, namedtuples or classes and then working on the data once it's been arranged in a way that makes it easier to work with, rather than trying to do a ton of convoluted stuff with a single list.

Comment: Yes, you're right. It's actually genome data from a Basic Local Alignment program. I thought that maybe If I could just modify the code that I already have I might be able to get most of the genes I'm looking for...I'm quite close, I just need to pick out the pairs and then compare the elements that correspond to them.

Comment: @BogusRoads Check my updated answer. Using `grouper()` it should be much easier.

Comment: @BogusRoads, if you show the real structure of your original data(as it looks like on file for example), I am sure you will get splendid answers.

Comment: @Lattyware Thanks! I will certainly look into this.. I will try to write the program first in a more linear way and then try to incorporate your advice. Thanks again!

Comment: Yo really have to separate a statement of the PROBLEM from your thoughts on the SOLUTION. I can't see any problem statement here. But it sounds like you want an iterator which suppresses/compresses n adjacent identical items into single items. Not sure if you want it to treat pairs (n=2) differently to n>=3? But please go back and state the PROBLEM.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Edit:

Right, with the new information in the OP, this becomes much simpler. Use [the `itertools` `grouper()` recipe](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) to group the data for each person into tuples:

```
import itertools

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    """Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"""
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return itertools.zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

data = ['John', 'Sally', '5', '10', '11', '4', 'John', 'Sally', '3', '7', '7', '10', 'Bill', 'Hallie', '4', '6', '2', '1']

grouper(data, 6)
```

Now your data looks like:

```
[
    ('John', 'Sally', '5', '10', '11', '4'), 
    ('John', 'Sally', '3', '7', '7', '10'), 
    ('Bill', 'Hallie', '4', '6', '2', '1')
]
```

Which should be easy to work with, by comparison.

---

Old Answer:

If you need to make more arbitrary links, rather than just checking continuous values:

```
def offset_iter(iterable, n):
    offset = iter(iterable)
    consume(offset, n)
    return offset

data = ['a', 'a', 'x', 'c', 'e', 'e', 'f', 'f', 'f']

offset_3 = offset_iter(data, 3)

for item, plus_3 in zip(data, offset_3): #Naturally, itertools.izip() in 2.x
    print(item, plus_3)                  #if memory usage is important.
```

Naturally, you would want to use semantically valid names. The advantage to this method is it works with arbitrary iterables, not just lists, and is efficient and readable, without any ugly, inefficient iteration by index. If you need to continue checking once the offset values have run out (for other conditions, say) then use [`itertools.zip_longest()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html?highlight=groupby#itertools.zip_longest) ([`itertools.izip_longest()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html?highlight=groupby#itertools.izip_longest) in 2.x).

Using [the `consume()` recipe from `itertools`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html?highlight=groupby#itertools-recipes).

```
import itertools
import collections

def consume(iterator, n):
    """Advance the iterator n-steps ahead. If n is none, consume entirely."""
    # Use functions that consume iterators at C speed.
    if n is None:
        # feed the entire iterator into a zero-length deque
        collections.deque(iterator, maxlen=0)
    else:
        # advance to the empty slice starting at position n
        next(itertools.islice(iterator, n, n), None)
```

I would, however, greatly question if you need to re-examine your data structure in this case.

---

Original Answer:

I'm not sure what your aim is, but from what I gather you probably want [`itertools.groupby()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html?highlight=groupby#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> data = ['a', 'a', 'x', 'c', 'e', 'e', 'f', 'f', 'f']
>>> grouped = itertools.groupby(data)
>>> [(key, len(list(items))) for key, items in grouped]
[('a', 2), ('x', 1), ('c', 1), ('e', 2), ('f', 3)]
```

You can use this to work out when there are (arbitrarily large) runs of repeated items. It's worth noting you can provide `itertools.groupby()` with a `key` argument that will group them based on any factor you want, not just equality.

Answer (score 5):

So it sounds like you are trying to compare elements in your list at various fixed offsets. perhaps something like this could help you:

```
for old, new in zip(lst, lst[n:]):
    if some_cond(old, new):
        do_work()
```

### Explanation:

`lst[n:]` returns a copy of lst, starting from the nth (mind the 0-indexing) element

```
>>> lst = [1,2,2,3];
>>> lst[1:]
[2,2,3]
```

`zip(l1, l2)` creates a new list of tuples, with one element from each list

```
>>> zip(lst, lst[1:])
[(1, 2), (2, 2), (2, 3)]
```

Note that it stops as soon as either list runs out. in this case, the offset list runs out first.

for a list of tuples, you can "upack directly" in the loop variable, so

```
for old, new in zip(lst, lst[1:])
```

gives loops through the elements you want (pairs of successive elements in your list)

Comment: +1, this is the best option when it comes to looping over neighbour elements - no ugly looping by index. The better version of this is to do `itr = iter(lst)` `next(itr)`, then use `itr` instead of `lst[n:]` - that way it works with iterables that don't support slicing.

Comment: as @Lattyware mentions, using iterators would make this code more efficient. Figured i was introducing enough new concepts as it was for the moment

Comment: It's not really about efficiency, more about flexibility. Not everything is a list.

Comment: This is a nice answer but may be it is the opposite case and you need memory efficiency not flexibility, in this case zip() doubles the memory requirements.

Comment: As discussed above, iterator versions (e.g. `izip`) are better for lots of reasons, but were left out here for simplicity

Comment: I think this is the best answer, I was just responding to Lattyware's statement that "It's not really about efficiency, more about flexibility".

Comment: @elyase I use 3.x, so I just used `zip()` - I'll add a note about `izip()` in 2.x. The method in my answer is more efficient memory-wise (it doesn't produce sliced lists), and is more flexible.

Comment: @Lattyware, I think your answer is the purest one.

Answer (score 1):

As a general idea, if you are trying to look ahead a certain number of places, you can do a few things:

1. In the loop check (I.e. count < length), you'll need to check on the max field. So in your example, you wanted to go 16 spaces. This would mean that you would need to check count < (length - 16). The downside is that your last elements (the last 16) won't be iterated over.
2. Check inside the loop to make sure the index is applicable. That is, on each if statement start with: if(I+16 < length && logic_you_want_to_check). This will allow you to continue through the loop, but when the logic will fail because its out of bounds, you won't error out.
3. Note- this probably isn't what you want, but ill add it for completeness. Wrap around your logic. This will only work if wrap arounds can be considered. If you literally want to check the 16th index ahead of your current index (I.e like a place in a line perhaps), then wrapping around doesn't really suit well. But if don't need that logic, and want to model your values in a circular pattern, you can modulus your index. That is: if array[i] == array [(i + 16)%length(array)] would check either 16 ahead or wrap around to the front of the array.

Answer (score -2):

If you adhere to ["Practicality beats purity"](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):

```
for idx, element in enumerate(yourlist[n:]):
    if yourlist[idx] == yourlist[idx-n]
    ...
```

If you don't care about memory efficiency go for second's answer. If you want the purest answer then go for Lattyware's one.

Comment: -1. Your edit now makes the same mistake in a slightly better way.

Comment: That doesn't allow you to access the next element.

Comment: @Lattyware, you are right, i answered to quickly,:-), fixed now.

Comment: This is still a terrible way of doing it. Looping by index is bad - that was what your post originally (correctly) said. It's also what your post now does.

Comment: Well thats what he wants, see comments to his question, given his comments I think my answer is now the simplest one.

Comment: It's not a good answer, its how he needs his solution to his problem to be modified to work, but its a sub-optimal way of solving the problem (either slightly or very, depending on information he hasn't given us).

Comment: @Lattyware, The problem is defined in terms of fixed offsets so indexing is appropiate here, I do like second's answer but I still think this answer doesn't deserve downvotes being simple, readable(especially for the OP) and not inferior in terms of speed.

Comment: Iterating by index essentially type-checks on the object being an indexable sequence, an arbitrary restriction which makes your code less flexible. Why do that when there are well-established ways to do the same thing without that issue? It may be easier to do `for line in open(...):`, but I'd never do it because using `with` to open files is preferable.

Comment: @Lattyware, In this problem (because of the offset) the sequence has to be indexable, remember "practicality beats purity", of course I could always go so complex as I want(not the case here but you get the point) to make my code so general as possible, but this doesnt mean that practical code deserves -2.

Comment: An iterable can happily have order and not allow indexing.

Comment: Sure but again "practicality beats purity", :-)

Comment: @elyase I don't see that iterating by index here is practicality. It's more of a pain (as proved by the question), than the equivalent code.

Comment: @Lattyware, More of a pain than trying to wrap your head around understanding iterating a zip() list? Try to see it from the OP's perspective.

Comment: So the argument is that it's hard to understand `zip()`? I don't see that. It's not the easiest concept in the world, but it's pretty core to Python, and we can't just not use features because they are not obvious, by that logic, we shouldn't use list comprehensions, or other nice features.

Comment: @Lattyware, I am using you logic, you mentioned that list indexing is a pain.

Comment: It's a pain because it's *inflexible* - why use Python if you are going to write code like you are using an inflexible language?

Comment: @Lattyware, because in some specific cases it is more practical to use it this way.

Comment: @elyase I still don't see how it's more practical. It's not nice to read, it's not nice to write, and it's less flexible. How does that equate to more practical?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30218/discussion-between-elyase-and-lattyware)